# Not able to hide hidden files / folders from nautilus broswer

Tags: unity, 14.04, nautilus

This is the issue in Ubuntu 14.04

I am not able to hide hidden files/folders permanently from nautilus browser. i am able to hide hidden files/folders from nautilus browser temporarily but when i am restarting the machine it automatically showing the hidden files/folders in the nautilus browser.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the preferences (`edit -> preferences`) then click the

```
[✔] Show hidden and backup files
```

option, so it is unchecked.

Comment: Beside this: you can also create a file ".hidden" in a directory and include the filenames of the files to hide in this file.

Comment: Also the keyboard short cut ctrl+H will hide or unhide the files when ever you want

Comment: Although Ctrl+H doesn't always change the setting permanently (it  does occasionally).